# assign priorities to todo items based on position in directory

Tags: org-mode, org-agenda, todo

I'm very new to extending Emacs.  I just started using org-agenda and I'm loving it so far.  My approach to todos is probably more granular than most: I have my major goals as separate org files and separate directories, which I call *paths*, e.g.

```
paths
├── master_path.org
├── get_fit
│   └── get_fit_path.org
├── get_healthy
│   └── get_healthy_path.org
├── get_productive
│   ├── deep-work.pdf
│   ├── get_productive_path.org
│   ├── get_productive_path.org~
│   └── Getting-Things-Done-book.pdf
├── learn_emacs
│   ├── eintr.pdf
│   ├── emacs_guide_1.pdf
│   ├── emacs_guide_2.pdf
│   ├── #learn_emacs_path.org#
│   ├── learn_emacs_path.org
│   └── Writing GNU Emacs Extensions - Bob Glickstein.pdf
├── learn_IT
│   ├── clean_architecture.pdf
│   ├── data_structures_and_algs_python.pdf
│   ├── learn_computer_networks
│   │   └── #learn_computer_networks.org#
│   ├── learn_databases
│   ├── learn_data_structures_and_algorithms
│   │   └── notes
│   │       ├── linked-lists.org
│   │       └── linked-lists.org~
│   ├── learn_IT_business_analysis
│   ├── learn_IT_path.org
│   ├── learn_IT_path.org~
│   ├── learn_programming_languages
│   │   └── learn_python
│   │       └── notes
│   │           └── how_python_works.org
│   ├── learn_software_engineering
│   ├── learn_software_testing
│   │   ├── laboon.pdf
│   │   └── #learn_software_testing_path.org#
│   ├── learn_version_control
│   └── notes
```

The org files labeled _path.org may contain the name of a subfolder that contains futher org files containing todo items.

For example:

## learn_IT_path.org

```
* TODO learn programming languages [#A]
* TODO learn databases
```

## Requirement 1

Now, because there is a folder called "learn_programming_languages" at the same level as `learn_IT_path.org`, this means any todos therein should automatically be assigned [#A] priority.  How can I do this?

## Requirement 2

If a nested org file that inherits a priority status from its parent is given a priority status within that file, the statuses are combined into a string, e.g.

```
# learn_programming_languages_path.org
* TODO learn python [#A]
* TODO learn APL [#C]
```

i.e. `learn Python` would end up with a priority [#AA], while `learn APL` gets [#AC]

If I assigned [#A] to `learn_IT` in `master_path.org`, then, `learn Python` would get [#AAA]

The order of todo items in org-agenda would be displayed accordingly.

Would this functionality be hard to do for someone new to extending emacs?

Comment: I'd use tags and/or categories for this, not priorities. Those can be assigned at file-level without having to alter the file content if you relocate the it. I guess what you want can be done, probably without much pain, but I don't think that it's a good strategy in the long run.

Comment: https://emacs.stackexchange.com/tags/elisp/info